# QML: How to save states for delegate in a listview

Tags: listview, delegates, qml, states

I have a `listView` of buttons. The button definition sits in its own qml file and is used as delegate.

```
delegate: ProgramButton { 
    state: stateFromModel
}
```

I defined states for the buttons, which should be set through a property of my `listModel`. This works initially, but if the button goes out of view through scrolling, and later I scroll back the state seems to have been forgotten.

The problem is, as the Qt documentation says, [the states should never be saved in delegates](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html).

However, what is the right way to set the states of a button then through a `listView` property?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is right on this point. At least when it comes to those views that instantiate only those delegates that are visible.

So the solution is obvious: *don't store it in the delegate* - But where could you store it?

If you don't want to preserve the initial state in the model, the model would be the easiest place. In this case you need to listen to stateChange-signals and write back the new state to the model.
Or - even better - change the state directly in the *model*. Due to the binding of `state -> model.stateFromModel` it will apply the change automatically to the button.

If that is not possible, you need to create persistent objects to store the state. This could either be a `JSObject` (aka var: ({}) aka Map) or you could instantiate a `QObject` with a `Instantiator` for each entry of your `ListView` and store the data in the according `QObject` using `myInstantiator.objectAt(index)` to retrieve the corresponding object.

The last way that spontaneously comes to my mind, is using a `DelegateModel` like this:

```
DelegateModel {
    id: dm
    model: myOriginalModel
    delegate: ProgrammButton {
        state: stateFromModel
        onStateChanged: DelegateModel.inPersistedItems = 1
    }
}
```

There you add the delegate upon stateChange to a special group [`persistedItems`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html#inPersistedItems-attached-prop) which prevents them from being destroyed when leaving the view.

Finally you use the `DelegateModel` as model for your `ListView` and don't set a `delegate` there.